# Source control strategy for Ionic / Cordova project when building for different platforms

Tags: git, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I find myself facing the same problem everytime I need to pull or commit code.
Here is the issue:

I have two computers, a Mac and a Windows, the latter for web dev and android builds, the other only for pulling my code, building the iOS app, and publishing it.
This has been working smoothly for a while.
But now the app has grown bigger, and I find myslef having to install some version A.B.C of a plugin on android, and an other X.W.Z on iOS.
Or having a plugin on one platfrom and not on the other.
Which quickly becomes a nightmare to deal with when jumping from one computer to the other.
I also reached the conclusion that I should version control some of the files generated by cordova, such as gradle files and info.plist, and some other config files so that I can understand better what's happening if the app is suddenly not building.
Not to mention package.json and package-lock.json that get updated by each Windowa/MacOs all the time.

So I would like to know if other people are facing the same issues, how do you guys deal with it? Any smarter solutions out there?

I was thinking about creating a script that copies all config files for a given platform including package.json and config.xml to a platfom specific folder everytime a successfull build is made. and version igonore those files. so they never get pushed or pulled from the remote (unless it's a first install)

Again, I don't know if this is a good approach and I would like to hear your opinions

Answer (score 0):

First of all isnt it good if you will build your android app in your MACOS instead of Windows :).
If you are facing any issue in MAC while building android then I can help you resolve that issue.

Ideally, package.json, package-lock.json, and config.xml should not be committed to git every time while you are pushing it to git. It should be updated whenever you are adding a plugin or updating package version of the plugin.

We follow the same in our team as my team members have windows, ubuntu, and MAC OS machines.